# Can anyone explain meaning of this phrase "I might as well be in OT". It has been used in online chatting

Tags: phrase-meaning

"I might as well be in OT" someone has used this phrase during online conversation and I don't understand the meaning of this phrase.

Conversation:
A: Can you tell me a bedtime story?
B: Bedtime story or bedtime fantasies?
A: Story. But quickly before I fall asleep.
B: I hate running after your time. It just feels like I am on a task. I might as well be in OT.

Comment: The question lacks context and research. I googled and found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_therapy

Comment: I have found the same information but it's the answer bcos that conversation were not about therapy it anything medical.

Comment: I think @Mari-LouA is correct.  Person B compares the feeling of "being on task" to Occupational Therapy.

Comment: OT has lots of meanings: overtime, occupied territory, on tour, Online Teacher, Overseas Teacher, orientation tour...   https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/OT But if you don't understand what someone means I suggest you take the unusual and novel action of asking them.

Comment: Flagged because my reasons are those of @StuartF -- we really need more context because there's too many different OTs. I thought of off-topic myself.

Comment: Or Old Testament?

Comment: If you don't know what OT means, do what we do: guess. As a joke, the exact meaning is not as important as understanding that B is exaggerating. If *overtime*, it means *for all the extra work of this task, I might as well be making money on overtime work.*

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the abbreviation 'OT' varies depending on the context in which it is used.  Here are some examples:

In healthcare: Occupational Therapy or Occupational Therapist

In forums where questions are asked/answered: Off topic

In telecommunications: Office of Telecommunications

In the Bible: Old Testament

In sport: Over time

Slang: Out there or out of town, or over there, denoting being away

Be aware, however, that it can also be used as a code word for having sex: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OT

Who would have thought it?